# Data modeling on cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I have an email marketting project, after long time researched, I decided to 
use cassandra to store my data.

My business is to allow my customers to create campaign, then import users from my users database, 
then send an email to them. After receive our email, the user maybe do some actions (open, view item, buy, complain, unsubscribe ...), I will log this actions based on its campaign.

My data structure is :

- Each custommer can create one or more campaigns.
- Each campaign include a alot of users.
- Each user can do zero or many actions on a campaign.

This is my first time with cassandra, I've searched and read many source from google but was still 
confusing about how my data modeling.

**Update: my queries**

I need to do the below queries:

1. List all campaigns in system
2. List all campaigns for a customer
3. Insert the action log whenever user did an action on a campaign
4. List all users in a campaigns with the actions that they did, including the occurred 
   time for each action (as a table, with paging)

   - The columns is actions
   - Each row is an user
   - Each cell is the occurred time for action on user

**Please give me an idea or introduce some articles for me on how to model my data?**

Thanks very much.

Comment: @Chiron is correct that you must first ask yourself how you need to query the data.  If you give some information about your queries, perhaps we can help lead you to the correct data model.

Comment: I'm sorry for lately reply, it was night at my location. I've update my question.

Answer (score 3):

In Cassandra, you model your tables according to your queries; not to the relation between your entities. This means duplicated data is ok, normal and encouraged. Remember, there are no relations between your tables.

So if your query is about listing all campaigns that belong to a customer, this means that your 'customer' table should contains denormalized data. The same goes to rest of your queries.

Comment: I've update my question to add the queries. Please take a look.